# order by date in txt file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, linq-to-xml

i made a program that takes release date and title from IMDB api and saves them in them in .txt file...can i order them by date somehow

[image]

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim _reg As Regex = New Regex("http://www.imdb.com/title/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/*?", _
              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

        Dim value As String = TextBox1.Text

        Dim m As Match = _reg.Match(value)

        If (m.Success) Then
            Dim key As String = m.Groups(1).Value
            Dim url As String = "http://mymovieapi.com/?id=" + key + "&type=xml&plot=none&episode=0&lang=en-US&aka=simple&release=simple&business=0&tech=0"
            Dim Document As XDocument = XDocument.Load(url)
            Dim title = Document.Root.Element("title").Value()
            Dim releaseDate = Date.ParseExact(Document.Root.Element("release_date").Value,
                  "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture)
            TextBox2.Text = "Release Date: " & releaseDate & "  /   Title: " & title
        Else : TextBox2.Text = "Please use IMDB links"
        End If
        Button2.Enabled = True
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim Writer As System.IO.StreamWriter
        Writer = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Azer\Documents\Movies.txt", True)
        Writer.Write(TextBox2.Text & vbCrLf)
        Writer.Close()
        Button2.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim Reader As System.IO.StreamReader
        Reader = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Azer\Documents\Movies.txt")
        Dim tempstring As String
        Do
            tempstring = Reader.ReadLine()
            TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text + tempstring + vbCrLf
        Loop Until tempstring = ""
        Reader.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        TextBox3.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you just need to sort them once?  Or will the text file grow over time and need to be sorted every time it's modified?  Or do you only need to sort when reading back from the text file?  Please elaborate.  Also, please show the code you're using to do these things.  So far all you're really asking is if it's possible to sort by date, and the answer to that is yes.  But without any actual code we can't really be more specific.

Comment: text file will grow over time and it needs to be sorted everytime,code is in pastebin link because its too big to post it here as whole

Comment: If you need to re-sort the entire file (so that it's stored in a sorted state) each time then you're going to need to read in the entire file each time (into a collection of some sort), add the new content to the collection, sort the collection, and write the entire file back (to include the new data).  In general databases are a _lot_ easier to work with for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David said, a database would make this a lot easier.  However, if you can't use a database (or have some other reason for doing it this way), here's one way to approach it.

Make a small class that holds the information (to make it easier to sort, like this:

```
Public Class MovieInfo

    Public Property As DateTime
    Public Title As String
End Class
```

Next, read the current file (if it exists) and populate a `List<MovieInfo>` with the data in it.

```
Dim movies As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Azer\Documents\Movies.txt")

Dim movieParts = From m in movies
                 Select m.Split(New String() { "/", ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim parsedDate As DateTime

Dim movieData As List(Of MovieInfo) = (From mi In movieParts
                                       Select New MovieInfo With
                                       {
                                           .ReleaseDate = _
      If(DateTime.TryParseExact(mi(1).Trim, "dd.MM.yyyy", _
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
         System.Globalization.DateTimStyle.None, _
         parsedDate), parsedDate, DateTime.MinValue),
                                           .Title = mi(3).Trim()
                                       }.ToList()
```

Essentially the code above reads the text file into an array (one line per element), and then using LINQ splits each line into 4 parts based on : and /.  Then it takes the result of that query and builds a List of MovieInfo, with the date string converted to DateTime for easy sorting.

The `DateTime.TryParseExact` takes an input string of the specified format (in this case, dd.MM.yyyy) and if possible converts it to a DateTime object.  If it's successful, it returns true and the DateTime value is in the parsedDate variable.  If it's not true, I use the MinValue for DateTime for the ReleaseDate property of the MovieInfo class.

After that, you'll get the new data from your API call and add it to the List of MovieInfo (you'll probably want to eliminate any duplicates).  Since you didn't post the format of the data from the API, it's rather hard for me to give you a code sample to parse it, but in a nutshell you can build a second list of MovieInfo objects and then merge the existing and new list together.

Then you sort the List of MovieInfo and overwrite the original text file.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
movieData.Sort(Function(x, y) y.ReleaseDate.CompareTo(x.ReleaseDate))

Dim output As New StringBuilder()

For Each info As MovieInfo in movieData
    output.Append("Release Date: ")
    output.Append(info.ReleaseDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))
    output.Append(" / Title: ")
    output.Append(info.Title)
    output.Append(Enviroment.NewLine)
Next

File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Azer\Documents\Movies.txt", output.ToString())
```

This code sorts the list with a lambda expression to put the movies in date order (newest to oldest).  It then uses a StringBuilder with a For Each loop to build the output, and then writes it to the file (overwriting the file if it already exists).

Note that if you reverse the x and the y in the Sort, you'll get oldest to newest by date.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines("your file name")
System.Array.Sort(allLines)
IO.File.WriteAllLines("your file name", allLines) 'assuming you want to write the file
```

Comment: No. The dates are not in a sortable format. Also, it relies too much on the date always being the first element of a line.